# How do I watch canon Kenshin content?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

I have watched the anime in full. I understand that canon stops at ep 62. What are the other animated contents that cover the canon story **to the fullest**?

Referring Wikipedia, there were two OVAs. Rurouni Kenshin: Trust & Betrayal seems canon without controversy. Rurouni Kenshin: Reflection was declared non-canon by the author, but I guess it was sourced from canon.

So my best guess is, I must watch Trust & Betrayal and then Reflection to get the canon story. Is my guess correct or did I miss something?

---

What parts of the manga have been not-animated? Are there upcoming projects that cover the canon story?

Comment: `Are there upcoming projects that cover the canon story?` Usually, you can check such news on ANN or other anime news site. We don't answer such questions, since we are always behind the news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're gonna want to watch Trust & Betrayal, then Reflection.  While the ending is not what the author wanted, its still semi-canon and good.  It also covers some of the final arc (Jinchuu Arc) at the end of ova 1 and beginning of ova 2.  Also the fight animations and soundtrack are great. Also worth watching if for nothing else than the reinvented fights (which are more realistic) is Rurouni Kenshin: New Kyoto Arc.

Then I would go back and read the manga after where Trust & Betrayal left off, it covers a lot of details that really add to the story and overall depth to characters (like sanosuke's past)

Comment: So New Kyoto movies cover canon ground just like the OVAs. Should I watch that after the OVAs?

Comment: New Kyoto is not canon.  Well sorta its a retelling with some elements different. Many think its a poor retelling since they had to rush the kyoto arc into 2 movies.  I only suggested it because the fights are great, and shows you a more realistic version of kenshin's fights.

Comment: Example is Usui never fights Saitou and the final battle is on the ship than in the cave.